# Socket.io - Corrupt response message on connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io, debian

I was testing some Socket.io examples but I couldn't get them to work and I received no error messages. After some testing I noticed that there were characters in front of the JSON string in the response messages vom the server.

[image: Response screenshot]

I don't know where these characters come from.

I have already updated NodeJS and Socket.io and tried to reinstall both but it didn't change anything.

NodeJS is running on a Debian wheezy server.

Comment: I have these characters as well but my socket.io app works as expected. Maybe you have an error in other place. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am so blind.. I was hung up on the response message and didn't check the client-side code enough. I just missed a character in a event listener and now it's working.